# convert JSON to java Object GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

```
{
"created_at": "Thu Jun 13 09:27:27 +0000 2013",
"id": 345110157237297150,
"id_str": "345110157237297152",
"text": "@sagarzope2 good afternoon 2nd retweet",
"source": "web",
"truncated": false,
"in_reply_to_status_id": 345109774226030600,
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": "345109774226030593",
"in_reply_to_user_id": 1512890215,
"in_reply_to_user_id_str": "1512890215",
"in_reply_to_screen_name": "sagarzope2",
"user": {
    "id": 1512890215,
    "id_str": "1512890215",
    "name": "sagar zope",
    "screen_name": "sagarzope2",
    "location": "",
    "description": "",
    "url": null,
    "entities": {
        "description": {
            "urls": []
        }
    },
    "protected": false,
    "followers_count": 0,
    "friends_count": 10,
    "listed_count": 0,
    "created_at": "Thu Jun 13 09:23:17 +0000 2013",
    "favourites_count": 0,
    "utc_offset": null,
    "time_zone": null,
    "geo_enabled": false,
    "verified": false,
    "statuses_count": 5,
    "lang": "en",
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "is_translator": false,
    "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
    "profile_background_image_url": "",
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "profile_image_url": "",
    "profile_image_url_https": "",
    "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "default_profile": true,
    "default_profile_image": true,
    "following": false,
    "follow_request_sent": false,
    "notifications": false
},
"geo": null,
"coordinates": null,
"place": null,
"contributors": null,
"retweet_count": 0,
"favorite_count": 0,
"entities": {
    "hashtags": [],
    "symbols": [],
    "urls": [],
    "user_mentions": [
        {
            "screen_name": "sagarzope2",
            "name": "sagar zope",
            "id": 1512890215,
            "id_str": "1512890215",
            "indices": [
                0,
                11
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"favorited": false,
"retweeted": false,
"lang": "en"
```

}

Can any one suggest me the classes stucture that are required in this JSON to convert to java object

Comment: Your JSON is not valid as well.

Comment: don't think this is valid json...errors everywhere

Comment: I suggest you going through Gson docs. You seem to have similar question in past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064725/complex-json-to-java-object-conversion-using-gson again with no attempt shown

Comment: check out now edited it now its a valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but I will try to answer this..

First of all, it depends on your requirement. For example, if you need just a few fields you can fetch them directly, without parsing the json.

If you want to create java objects, well, you have just to understand how JSON works.

{} -> object

[] -> array

so if you have: `{"foo":"bar"}`

your object will be

```
public class Object {
   private String foo;
}
```

if you have: `{"foo":"bar","innerObj":{"fizz":"buzz"}}`

your object will be

```
public class Object {
   private String foo;
   private InnerObj innerObj;
}

public class InnerObj {
   private String fizz;
   private InnerObj innerObj;
}
```

Now do your consideration.

Read about JSON: http://json.org/

Get a library like Jackson or GSON.